# Angular routing issue - url updating but not page

Tags: angular

I have two components, home and welcome. Welcome has a button which when clicked, should bring me to the 'home' page. Instead, it updates the url to "http://localhost:4200/home" and does nothing else. The button remains, instead of being replaced with the home components content.

app.module.ts

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { WelcomeComponent } from './pages/welcome/welcome.component';
import { HomeComponent } from './pages/home/home.component';

const appRoutes: Routes = [
  { path: 'welcome', component: WelcomeComponent },
  { path: 'home', component: HomeComponent }
];

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    WelcomeComponent,
    HomeComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot(
      appRoutes
    )
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

welcome.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-welcome',
  templateUrl: './welcome.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./welcome.component.css']
})
export class WelcomeComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private router: Router) { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  myFunction() {
    this.router.navigate(['/home'])
  }

}
```

welcome.html

```
<button class="btn btn-success" type="button" id="loginButton" (click)="myFunction()">Sign In</button>
```

home.html

```
<p>
  home works!
</p>
```

Comment: have u included `<router-outlet></router-outlet>`  in app.component.js ?

Also try to add default and wildcard route configuration like `{ path: '', redirectTo: 'home', pathMatch: 'full' },` and `{ path: '**', redirectTo: 'home' }`

Comment: any error in console?

Comment: Have you include <router-outlet></router-outlet> in app.component.html ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Comments were correct. Adding default paths and the router-outlet tag fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
in app.module.ts:-

```
import { NgModule } from "@angular/core";
import { Routes, RouterModule } from "@angular/router";
import { LayoutComponent } from "./layout.component";


const appRoutes: Routes = [{
   path: "",
   component: LayoutComponent,
   children: [{
       path: "",
          redirectTo: "welcome"
    },
    {
       path: "welcome",
          loadChildren: "./welcome/welcome.module#WelcomeModule"(your path)
     },
     {
        path: "home",
          loadChildren: "./home/home.module#HomeModule"(your path)
     }
    }
  ];
```

in welcome.html

```
<button class="btn btn-success" type="button" id="loginButton" routerLink="/welcome" [routerLinkActive]="['router-link-active']">Sign In</button>
```

Comment: He did not mention lazy loading modules